# Select child_added, firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a query in Firebase, and I have as data the uid, how can I improve the query to get (name, surname) if I have a structure like the following.

I just want the data of the logged in user.

[image]

My code is this:

```
    const v_uName = document.getElementById('id_nameU');
  var v_userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  console.log(v_userId);
  var v_ref1 = firebase.database().ref().child('/ad_persona/');
  v_ref1.on('child_added', function(v_snap1){
    v_ref1.child(v_snap1.key).on('child_added', function(v_snap2){
      v_ref1.child(v_snap1.key).child(v_userId).on('value', function(v_snap3){
        console.log(v_snap3.val());
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: "Improve the query"?

Comment: At this moment it does not work, I need the data of the user who is logged in @GrayCygnus

Comment: The `perfil1` and `perfil2` are making life needlessly difficult. Remove that and you can simply attach your listener to `firebase.database().ref().child('ad_persona').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)`.

Comment: It looks great, if I delete profile, what would be another solution to organize my users by profile ("administrator", "editor", "viewer" ...) @FrankvanPuffelen